# ItemsControl with VirtualizingStackPanel disables horizontal animations in ScrollViewer

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm building a custom XAML control for a UWP app that relies heavily on a ScrollViewer with snap points.

I would really like the content that is bound to the control to be virtualized, so I'm using an ItemsControl. However, when I use a VirtualizingStackPanel in the ItemsControl, and then call ChangeView() on the ScrollViewer to a specific HorizontalOffset, the animation effect when scrolling to the new offset is disabled (it just jumps directly to the offset). If I simply replace the VirtualizingStackPanel with a StackPanel (no virtualization), the horizontal animations work.

Question: Does anyone know how to use a VirtualizingStackPanel *and* enable horizontal animations when changing the offset?

Here is the C# adjusting the horizontal offset (the customScrollViewer is being accessed via tree-crawling, since it is part of the ControlTemplate style):

```
customScrollViewer.ChangeView(500, null, null, false);
```

And here is the XAML style for the ItemsControl:

```
       <Style x:Key="ItemsControlSnapStyle" TargetType="ItemsControl">
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                    <ScrollViewer
                        x:Name="customScrollViewer"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                        HorizontalSnapPointsType="Mandatory">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question, I could reproduce this behavior, and it looks by-design. Derive from [`VirtualizingStackPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.virtualizingstackpanel) document. **It can only be used to display items in an ItemsControl.** Generally. At the [remarks part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.virtualizingstackpanel#remarks), *Starting in Windows 8.1, ItemsStackPanel is used as the default ItemsPanel for ListView. If you modify the ItemsPanel, we recommend you use ItemsStackPanel or ItemsWrapGrid instead of VirtualizingStackPanel or WrapGrid.*

If we replace `VirtualizingStackPanel` with  `ItemsStackPanel`, and `ChangeView` method could work with animation. And `ItemsStackPanel` also support `virtualizes`. So we suggest you could use `ItemsStackPanel` as ItemsPanel for the ItemsControl.

```
<Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: It works great! I honestly thought I had hit a dead end, and was not expecting there to be a solution here. Thank you!