# How to bind data from outside Data Template in UWP

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to refer txtCount from inside DataTemplate I am missing PATH Or anything else can any one guide me. Thanks

```
 <UserControl   
xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core">    
 <Grid x:Name="mainGrid" Margin="2">     
    <TextBlock Name="txtCount" Text="1/1"></TextBlock> 
    <muxc:ItemsRepeater x:Name="dataRepeater" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Activities}">
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:ScheduleItem">
            <Button x:Name="btnMemoAct" >
                <Ellipse x:Name="BtnCircle" 
                             Width="25"
                             Height="25"                                                                 
                        ></Ellipse> 
                <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=btnMemoAct}">
                       
                        <Core:ChangePropertyAction 
                                TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=txtCount}"
                                PropertyName="Text"
                                Value="2/2"
                                />

                    </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </muxc:ItemsRepeater>       
</Grid>
```

Comment: I have run your code, and it works as except, it could pass `2/2` to txtCount after button click. Could you tell the problem you have encountered ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I am using this in user control, Not working here can you please share ur working code

Comment: Sure, please check sample [here](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/MvvmTest).

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT thanks for codeshare I am seeing the difference between ur and mine approach is I am using ItemsRepeater. Does this will not work with Items Repeater? I will use list view approach but how to render items horizontally because in list view items added vertically ?

Comment: Sure, if you want to make ListView horizontally, please refer this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61007885/7254781).